# Add basic page title and its teaser view in basic page

Tags: 7, nodes

I wanted to have one basic page, that allows me to add brief data about other basic pages like title and some data in teaser view. ie to create basic page, whose content is, some content of other basic pages.

I know that we can achieve this by using view. But I wanted to know if there is module available that allows me to do this, so that I can select the pages which are to be embed in the page I am creating.

Comment: If you know that views can solve your problem, why don't you go for it? It'll enable you to do what you require, rather than reinventing the wheel again.

Comment: But for that I have to create another content type for the pages that I need to embed, because I am not able to filter out the pages to be embed in this way.

Comment: You can filter the data on any other value, or create a new field to specify which ones you want (can be hidden in output). So you don't have to create a new content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Node Embed](http://drupal.org/project/node_embed) module.

Node Embed provides an input filter for CKEditor & FCKEditor integration allowing a content editor the ability to embed the rendering of nodes within the body/fields of another node.

Nice documentation for this module can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/1476024).